# Backpropagation in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, backpropagation

I tried to implement a neural network that uses [backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) for training it. As the title says I did it in Python 3.6, and tried to make it learn the XOR function.

When I run the code and test the network, the output is about 0.5, regardless of the input it gets, so obviously something wrong has happened in the training process.

The output does seem to be affected by the learning rate constant and the constant for momentum, but I've tried a large range of different combinations and values that I found reasonable, but with no success.

I'd be really grateful if someone could help me find out what's wrong.

I think it's easier if you can use Spyder if you want to try out the code, since you'll then get a complete list of all variables.

Here is the code:

First I make an array with all possible inputs, and an array with the answer for these inputs.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Error = []
OutArray = []

Xtrain = np.array([
        [0,0], 
        [0,1], 
        [1,0], 
        [1,1]
    ])

Ttrain = np.array([0,1,1,0])
```

Then I make the variable "biasNr", that states how many biases there are for each layer. The variable "Layers" defines how many neurons there are for each layer.

So here we have 2 inputs because of "Xtrain", but also a bias in the input layer, and bias in the hidden layer.

At the same time we have 2 neurons in the hidden layer, and one neuron in the output layer.

This is modular, so if we want more neurons in the hidden layers, we could have written: "Layers = np.array([3,2,1])", and "biasNr = np.array([1,0,1])

```
N = len(Xtrain)
D = 0

biasNr = np.array([1,1])

Layers = np.array([2,1])

L = len(Layers)
```

Then I concatenate the number of biases for the input layer, randomly initialize the weights and delta of the weights, which I use to be able to add momentum when training the network.

```
ones = np.array([[1]*N]).T
for i in range(biasNr[0]):
    Xtrain = np.concatenate((Xtrain,ones), axis = 1)

for i in range(N):
    if D < len(Xtrain[i]):
        D = len(Xtrain[i])

w = [0] * L
dw = [0] * L

for j in range(L):
    w[j] = []
    dw[j] = []
    for i in range(Layers[j]):
        if j == 0:
            Rw = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, D)
        else:
            Rw = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, Layers[j-1] + biasNr[j])

        dRw = Rw - Rw*0.01

        if i == 0:
            w[j] = Rw
            dw[j] = dRw
        else:
            w[j] = np.vstack((w[j], Rw))
            dw[j] = np.vstack((dw[j], dRw))
```

Then we have the sigmoid function:

```
def sigmodal(Y):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-Y))
```

And the function for a single neuron:

```
def nevron(inputs, weights):
    Y = inputs.dot(weights)
    Y = sigmodal(Y)

    return Y
```

The function for the whole network. "inputs" comes in as a 3x1 vector, while "layers" states how many neurons there are for each layer, and "bias states how many biases there are for each layer. "weights" comes in as a list of MxN matrices, where each MxN matrix contains the weights between each layer.

```
def MLP(inputs, layers, bias, weights):
    Y = 0
    S = []

    for j in range(len(layers)):
        R = []

        for i in range(layers[j]):
            Y = 0

            if j == 0: # if 1

                if layers[j] == 1:
                    Y = nevron(inputs, weights[j])
                else:
                    Y = nevron(inputs, weights[j][i])

            else: # else 1

                if layers[j] == 1:
                    Y = nevron(S[j-1], weights[j])
                else:
                    Y = nevron(S[j-1], weights[j][i])

            Yj = np.array([Y])

            if i == 0:
                R = np.array([Y])
            else:
                R = np.concatenate((R, Yj), axis=0)


        S.append(R)

        if j < len(bias)-1:
            for i in range(bias[j+1]):
                S[j] = np.concatenate((S[j], np.array([1])), axis=0)

    return S
```

Then I make a list that contains all the outputs for each neuron, named "sumN":

```
sumN = []
```

The function for training the network.

```
def trainMLP(trainIn, trainOut, layers, bias, learning_rate, momentum, cycles):
    global w
    global dw
    global sumN
    repeatLR = 1

    delta = []

    for x in range(len(layers)):
        delta.append(np.array([0.0]*layers[x]))

    for j in range(cycles): # Loop 1

        if j > (cycles * 0.9) and repeatLR == 1:
            learning_rate = learning_rate * 0.1
            repeatLR = 0

        for i in range(N): # Loop 2
            sumN = []
            Y = 0

            sumN = MLP(trainIn[i], layers, bias, w)
            Y = sumN[len(layers)-1]

            OutArray.append(Y)

            if j % (cycles/10) == 0:
                print(str(j) + "," + str(i), "In:", trainIn[i], "Out: ", Y)

                if i == 3:
                    print("===============================================")

            for h in range(len(layers)-1, -1, -1): # Loop 3

                for g in range(layers[h]): # Loop 4
                    sigDer = sigmodal(sumN[h][g])*(1 - sigmodal(sumN[h][g]))

                    if h == (len(layers)-1):
                        delta[h] = (trainOut[i] - Y) * sigDer

                        dw[h] = learning_rate * delta[h] * sumN[h-1] + momentum * dw[h]
                        Error.append(trainOut[i] - Y)
                    else:

                        delA = np.ndarray((len(delta[h+1]), 1), buffer = delta[h+1], dtype = float)

                        if layers[h] == 1:
                            wA = np.ndarray((len(w[h]), 1), buffer = w[h],dtype = float)
                        else:
                            wA = np.ndarray((len(w[h][g]), 1), buffer = w[h][g],dtype = float)

                        delta[h] = delA.dot(wA.T) * sigDer

                        dw[h][g] = learning_rate * delta[h] * sumN[h-1] + momentum * dw[h][g]

                    if layers[h] == 1:
                        w[h] = w[h] + dw[h]
                    else:
                        w[h][g] = w[h][g] + dw[h][g]
```

Function for testing the network:

```
def testMLP(trainIn, weights):
    print("------------------------------------")
    for i in range(N):
        Y = MLP(trainIn[i], Layers, biasNr, w)
        Y0 = Y[len(Y)-1]

        print(str(i), "In:", trainIn[i], "Out: ", Y0)

    print("------------------------------------")
```

And then I call the major functions to complete the process. Here the learning rate = 0.1, while the momentum = 0.5 :

```
trainMLP(Xtrain, Ttrain, Layers, biasNr, 0.1, 0.5, 10000)

testMLP(Xtrain, w)

plt.plot(Error)
plt.plot(OutArray)
```

EDIT:

Here is what I usually get as output. This is after 10'000 epocs:

```
0 In: [0 0 1] Out:  [ 0.38433476]
1 In: [0 1 1] Out:  [ 0.38330449]
2 In: [1 0 1] Out:  [ 0.70006104]
3 In: [1 1 1] Out:  [ 0.52599719]
```

The output that I want, since I'm learning the XOR function. Of course it won't be exactly 0 or 1, but it should be closer and more appearent if the value is closing onto 0 or 1:

```
0 In: [0 0 1] Out:  [ 0.0]
1 In: [0 1 1] Out:  [ 1.0]
2 In: [1 0 1] Out:  [ 1.0]
3 In: [1 1 1] Out:  [ 0.0]
```

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Since you haven't shown the results of tracing and debugging attempts, nor have you reduced this to a manageable size, I worry that you will get little help on this problem.

Comment: I understand and agree. My initial thought was that most of the code that I posted is relevant, as it's needed to understand how I've been thinking. But I agree, it's too much, and I dont know what to cut out while including code that may have an error in it. The functions "MLP" and "trainMLP" should definetly be included, but they're already 75% of the code, when combined. That made me consider offering money, since it's kinda massive. So I'm not sure what I should do. Make a new post? Try to narrow down to where I suspect the error is? I will still have to include all the code though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, anyway.

Comment: (1) Yes, include information on where you think the error is, including output from debugging traces; (2) Put your code into a single block, so we can cut & paste it easily for our debugging.